# How to 1-Hit kill an Enderman?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I'm wondering how to get a 1-Hit kill on an Enderman. I saw Somone on YouTube kill an Enderman in 1 hit with a melon slice. Does this or any other way work? Anything helps!

Comment: link to youtube video?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

If you saw that in an Etho's Lab video, he built an Endermen farm in the sky. The Endermen fall 42 or 43 blocks and that brings their health down to half a heart, so they can be one-hit killed. [LP Episode 151](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v9jA7CJ_KxI) shows the process of building it and [LP Episode 152](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AHtReA43AEQ) shows how it is working.

Comment: The endermen are unlike other mobs in that there one hit kill fall damage is not 23 blocks in height but 43. 44 and 45 will ensure a fall-damage kill, while 42 or 43 will allow for a one hit kill. If you'd like proof of this, watch my videos at user/letsplaymc2013

Comment: @ToazterWafflez just fyi, "this helps a lot" is what you mean. "allot" means something completely different.

Answer (score 2):

You can't 1h KO an Enderman with a melon slice.

Unless:

A) The melon slice is enchanted.  Even with the Potion of Strength II, a hit from a Melon Slice will in no way kill the Enderman in one hit, even with a critical.  Since you don't have a video, I'm assuming the melon slice was enchancted with, persay, a sharpness.  And since you can't enchant melon slices normally, it leads to:

B) The enderman were dropped a significant distance enough to not nearly kill them, but drop them down to half a heart, where a melon would instantly kill them on click.

Other than that, there is no other way to 1HKO an Enderman.

Comment: It could be possible that the Enderman had received prior fall damage, splash potion damage, etc.  Or suffocation (albeit rare)

Comment: Well the person who did it was Ethos. And he's really famous on YouTube. He was in the end and had cut it down into a big square with a wall around it and a rail cart track (?).

Comment: Those endermen were at half a heart damage - that farm spawns them and pushes them off the spawn pads so that they take fall damage but do not die.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to **fall damage**, a second way to "soften" Endermen so they are a one-hit kill is with **suffocation damage**.

Sethbling describes how to create a "poor man's Enderman farm" by suffocating the Endermen with solid blocks on sticky pistons:

If you feel like experimenting, you should be able to hook the mechanism up to a long timer that automatically extends and retracts the pistons.